# osdclock - Any way to center it in the screen?

Tags: linux-mint

I am running Linux Mint 20. Cinnamon edition.

I installed osdclock.
When I run
osd_clock
it displays it in the left bottom corner.

If I run
osd_clock -t
it runs on the top left corner.

I can run it at all 4 corner. I can also offset it using -o, but it only moves it at the vertical line. I can not seem to move it along the horizontal line...

But, is there any way to run it in the center of the screen?

Here is the man page
https://manpages.debian.org/testing/osdclock/osd_clock.1.en.html

Anyone familiar with that program?

Cheers.

Comment: As you've already been told, the app doesn't do that. You might look to `conky` as an option. It can display a clock, among other things, and be positioned anywhere you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You linked the manual for osdclock in your Question, and it says "No". The program is ancient. I don't think your feature is on the "will-be-implemented-soon" list.

So there is your answer. ... but having said that... :

There might be a workaround, where you specify leading spaces to the `-F` format parameter in order to "left-pad" with spaces. That only works in an optically pleasing way only if your Desktop background has the same color at least for the left half of the screen for the portion of height, where you plan to display the clock.

EDIT: After playing around `-F` parameters, OP @IP found, that "Spaces" don't work, but that there is a way to tell [strftime](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/manpages-dev/strftime.3.en.html) to pad using `".%_100c"`.

Comment: Cheers, that does work rather well. (Sorry, can not yet upvote). However, I am not sure how to make an "empty space" in this format. Perhaps someone knows? I used ____________ %c%________________ to center, which does work fairly ok, so long as I am on the bottom of the screen. If I wanted real center though... that would look ugly. Cheers.

Comment: @I.P Did you quote your spaces? Like so `-F "  LotsOfSpaces %c"` ?

Comment: that does sadly not work. (Spaces goes all bad for it.) However, ".%_100c" does (in case anyone should be interested). I was not able to get rid of the . at the start, as the _100 shift is otherwise not registered. Interestingly, for %a it does work... oh well. Anyway. I am happy with it :) Cheers and have  a nice day.

Comment: I'm glad i could help :)  For the leading ".": You could try replacing it with one of the Zero-Length unicode characters. Or the really slim vertical line on the left side of the character "box"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xdotool`.

`osd_clock` has name `XOSD` so something like:

```
xdotool search --name "XOSD" windowmove X Y
```

where `X` and `Y` are coordinates.

If you want you can check size of window by `getwindowgeometry` as well as size of monitor(s) by `xrandr --listmonitors`.

---

If you have *one* or *equal sized + same orientation* monitors you could perhaps do something like this:

```bsh
#! /bin/sh -

win_name=$1
x=${2:-0}
y=${3:-0}

eval "$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --limit 1 --all --name "$win_name" getwindowgeometry --shell)"
wmctrl -d | \
    awk \
    -v x="$x" \
    -v y="$y" \
    -v win_w="$WIDTH" \
    -v win_h="$HEIGHT" \
    -F "[ x]*" '
    $2 == "*" {
        x += $4 / 2 - win_w / 2
        y += $5 / 2 - win_h / 2
        print x, y
    }
' | xargs xdotool windowmove "$WINDOW"
```

Use as `./script <WINDOW-NAME> x y` where in this case `<WINDOW-NAME>` would be `XOSD` and `x` / `y` are optional fine tuning arguments.

With different sized monitors and perhaps tilted ones etc. one could still script it - (have one of those as well) - but more work, and perhaps not worth it.